# How do I avoid "SEVERE: Duplicate ID" warnings for my autodoc'd modules in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using rST/Sphinx to document my Python, however when building it's throwing warnings such as

```
...Code/doc/code.rst:3: SEVERE: Duplicate ID: "module-toast".
```

My Python source files are documented like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
.. module:: toast
    :synopsis: Processes the blobs produced by :mod:`bread`.
'''
# my inline-rST documented code...
```

And the rST files use the autodoc provided `automodule` directive to pull all the docstrings out and document all the members.

```
Toast
--------------------------------

.. automodule:: toast
    :members:
```

The above combo seems to work just fine, but the error seems to imply there is a proper way to do this.  If I remove the module directive from the top of my source file the error goes away, but then I can't add a synopsis option in the source that's picked up by Sphinx.

Answer (score 7):

One way around is to use `:noindex:` flag.

```
.. automodule:: toast
    :members:
    :noindex:
```

Then in your source code you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
.. module:: toast
    :synopsis: Processes the blobs produced by :mod:`bread`.
'''
```

There'll be no SEVERE warning and message in synopsis will appear in module index.

On the other side `:noindex:` will hide module from index if it doesn't have `.. module::` in their source file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, but I believe that the `automodule` directive will create a `module` directive on it's own.  Then, since you already have one specified, there are two, and thus you get a duplicate ID message.

You might try using the `currentmodule` directive in your module markup instead of `module`.  It seems like that *should* work, though I admit I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: `currentmodule` doesn't accept the `:synopsis:` option so I need to move that to the rST file, then having any `module` directive in the source is superfluous.  I'm wondering if what I want isn't possible (at present). `:/`

Answer (score 0):

The `:noindex:` for `automodule::` as written by simno helps but prevents the creation of perma-links and cross-links (e.g. `:func:`) won't work. 
When adding `:noindex:` to `module::` everything works as expected and you don't have to use `currentmodule`.